# get multiple value from map/tree

Tags: java, dictionary

I have a map where the key in an object with has multiple String field. I want to be able to crate a key where some of that field are null, and when i do a get(key) in the map retrieve multiple element, where all the string match, but the null value on the key match all.

If this is not clear, think about the key's variable as field of a table, and the get as a SELECT statement WHERE all not null key field must be equals, and null field are ignored.

As a real life example think about a key composed of Name, Surname, Location and Age. I want a Map (or similar) witch i can get all element with Name=XXX, NAME=XXX and AGE=YYY, NAME=XXX and LOCATION=ZZZ

multiple map (one for every key value) and then intersect the results, but it seems slow. Keeping a map for every combination may be a ram killer (think about 6 string filed, with median len of 10 char, and some thousand elements)

Comment: Have you considered using a database?

Comment: Yes, but i need the speed and flexibility of a map. Maybe an embedded db running on ram?

Comment: Implement your own Map<keytype, Arraylist<valuetype>> and override the 'put' method to append the value in the array of values instead of overwrite it so that it caches all values with the same key. After this you can use this for name, age, location... Sorry, cannot give your a full answer, must go now.

Comment: but that way i must have a map for every possible subkey, and when getting using multiple key intersect the resulting values.. This is a solution stated in the question, but seems inefficient.

Comment: If you want to use Key/Value concept to your system, I recommend MongoDB or Redis. You can google for it. However, if want to implement something like that in java. You should iterate all of collection members and check their types and so on. Good luck with that

Comment: @JuneyoungOh it is not a key-value concept, and your last sentence is wrong as only full iteration is needed with pre-filtered values, as already said in the answer and by inigoD. Also the DB "do it better", and i'm asking if someone know how to implement this (or has already implemented it) without all the setup/bloat/sql needed by a DB

Comment: I got your point. I need to think more Thanks